# Accessibility & HTML title tag separators - alternatives to the vertical line (pipe)

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, title

I am attempting to make a site a bit more screen reader friendly and in testing I noticed that a common pattern is quite annoying on a screen reader - the site is using a vertical line / pipe character as a separator in the `<title>` tag (e.g. `<title>Page Name | Site Name</title>`). When I use VoiceOver as a screen reader to do testing it is read as **"Page Name Vertical Line Site Name"** which sounds especially odd with the particular title of the site.

What are the best accessible alternatives to the pipe that also have no negative effect on SEO? I've tried a `<title>Page Name - Site Name</title>` and `<title>Page Name &middot; Site Name</title>` and they work okay, but I afraid they might have gotchas (e.g. reading as 'dash' or 'ampersand m i d d o t semicolon') on some edge case or causing chaos with SEO. Is there an accepted best practice for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pronunciation of punctuation or special characters varies by screen reader, so there is no optimal choice. While it is true that “vertical line” sounds odd, it’s an oddity that screen reader users are accustomed to, since the “|” is widely used—not that much in `title` elements, rather in link lists and other contexts. The use of an en dash “–” might help, as it is a normal punctuation character and might be just ignored or even handled in an advanced way (e.g., a pause followed by raised tone). On other other hand, a comma “,” or a colon “:” might do the same thing, or do better.

It is very unlikely that such choices have any impact on SEO, since search engines generally ignore punctuation and special characters. (They might notify some special characters in *some* contexts, e.g. distinguishing between C and C++.)

Depending on context and context language, you could also consider using purely verbal expressions, e.g. in English using “of” instead of a separator character. “New products of ACME Corporation” sounds better than “New products | ACME Corporation” (though the latter is in no way wrong). This may have a minor impact on SEO, since search engines may treat even small words like “of” as significant; but this would not matter much, due to the way people write things in search boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Using either a hyphen, or comma will have no effect on the site's SEO ranking.

But shorter titles often get more clicks from search (my own impression, backed by some data below), so think if you really need the site's name on every page?

Also, keep your title around 55 characters or so for best results in Google, the character count is trickier than it used to be, see http://moz.com/blog/new-title-tag-guidelines-preview-tool for a detailed explanation of some recent changes by Google. The current length is actually determined by pixel counts, not characters.

See this experiment for PPC CTR based on title lenghths: http://danzarrella.com/ppc-ad-line-lengths-and-clickthrough-rates.html#  (not SEO, but correlates with my own experience in organic results).